# R: Fatal error: creating temporary file for '-e' failed

Tags: r, linux, temporary-files

```
sessionInfo()
```

> R version 3.5.1 (2018-07-02) Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin15.6.0
>   (64-bit) Running under: macOS High Sierra 10.13.3

```
library(parallel)
makeCluster(detectCores() - 1)
```

Output in R:

> Fatal error: creating temporary file for '-e' failed

How can I solve this issue? Thank you!

Comment: You'll get this error if your operating system is having problems creating new files.  Try to create a new temporary file `touch foo.txt` under `/tmp`, `/home/youruser/` and `/var/tmp` where R/Rscript keeps its scratch files.  Check to see if your hard drive is full or if your hard drive is in read-only mode or other reason Rscript can't create a new temporary code file due to changed directory permissions.

Answer (score 2):

The `parallel` package appears to save tmp files to /var/tmp/.  The error `Fatal error: creating temporary file for '-e' failed` appears to be related to access issues with this location.  I was able to solve the issue by enabling permissions for this folder (in my case by mounting the location in a Docker/Singularity image).

Answer (score 0):

Can you confirm that the code based on the `Seurat`-included sample data works.

For example, does the following work?

```
library(Seurat)
res <- ScaleData(object = pbmc_small, vars.to.regress = c("nUMI"))
#Regressing out: nUMI
#  |======================================================================| 100%
#Time Elapsed:  2.64941716194153 secs
#Scaling data matrix
#  |======================================================================| 100%
```

Comment: It also showed the fatal error. That's why I cannot figure out what went wrong. It might not be because of the Seurat package; instead, it might be because of my setting in R or Mac?

Comment: @realm Yes, there might be a bigger/different issue. Can you run `traceback()` after the error has occurred and include the output in your original question?

Comment: Here is the output:

6: socketConnection("localhost", port = port, server = TRUE, blocking = TRUE, 
       open = "a+b", timeout = timeout)
5: newPSOCKnode(names[[i]], options = options, rank = i)
4: makePSOCKcluster(names = spec, ...)
3: parallel::makeCluster(num.cores)
2: RegressOutResid(object = object, vars.to.regress = vars.to.regress, 
       genes.regress = genes.use, use.umi = use.umi, model.use = model.use, 
       display.progress = display.progress, do.par = do.par, num.cores = num.cores)
1: ScaleData(object = pbmc, vars.to.regress = c("nUMI", "percent.mito"))

Comment: @realm Don't post code/errors in comments (comments are transient). I've added the `traceback` output to your original post.

Comment: @realm So it seems that the error is produced when setting up parallelisation using `parallel`. What does `makeCluster(detectCores() - 1)` give in an R terminal?

Comment: Did you mean that I type "makeCluster(detectCores() - 1)" in an R terminal? It showed "bash: syntax error near unexpected token `detectCores'"

Comment: @realm Yes, that's what I meant. I forgot to mention though that this requires an explicit `library(parallel)`.

Comment: @realm Ok. The good news is that we've narrowed down the issue. It's `parallel` that's causing the problem. It sounds like the current firewall settings on your Mac don't allow communication via sockets. Are you behind some restrictive company firewall? How to proceed depends on your computer & network infrastructure. Best to consult with your local sys admin/IT representative.

Comment: @realm Another option would be to disable all `parallel` steps; there seems to be a `ScaleData` parameter `do.par` to enable/disable process parallelisation. However, `do.par` is `FALSE` by default, so I'm not sure whether this actually bypasses any `parallel` calls.

Comment: set [do.par = F] did not help. Just found that when I [?ScaleData], it showed [Error in file(out, "wt") : cannot open the connection]. Everything just suddenly stopped working. By the way, I felt you might be right about firewell settings, so will consult with IT.

Comment: @realm Yes, I'm not surprised because `ScaleData` has `do.par = F` by default. To attract more attention you might want to rewrite your post and remove all the `Seurat` bits, as this has become an issue with `parallel`. The reproducible code is `makeCluster(detectCores() - 1)` which throws the error.